# Embedding iFrame in a button in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to embed an iframe in a wordpress button? I am using kadence blocks to add a button and gutenberg editor for my wordpress site. (the embedded iframe in a button is for the content page and not for the footer)

I added a button in my content page and I tried manually coding in the theme file editor but it does not work the way I want to. I want to embed an iframe where I click the button, the iframe will appear.